# Is it possible to rescind a web push notification

Tags: javascript, web, push-api

In the scenario that a push service sends push messages to multiple user agents and they all call showNotificafion. After one user agent acknowledges the notification is it possible to close the shown notification on all other user agents?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications#managing_redundant_notifications  Looks like this isn’t possible but there are some workarounds